# C# AccessViolationException unmanaged methods

Tags: c#, methods, crash, unmanaged

My program does automated clicks in a Windows Form, if the color of the pixel under the mouse has a specific color. Now the problem is that sometimes, maybe after an hour, or maybe after 5 hours of the program running (and working seemingly totally fine), the complete system (OS) crashes. Sometimes, I'm able to catch an AccessViolationException.
I'm pretty sure the crashing has got to do with the unmanaged methods I have to call for clicking the mouse and getting the color of a screen pixel. But I can't for the hell of it figure out what's wrong. I use the following code for mouse clicks:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy,
                           uint dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

public void DoMouseClick()
    {
            //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
            uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
            uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

And for getting the color of a pixel, I use this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

static public System.Drawing.Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y)
{
    IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
    Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
                     (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
                     (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    return color;
}
```

Both methods are mostly copy-pasted from the internet. I use this stuff as mentioned before in Windows Forms. A Forms.Timer is running the whole time, don't know if that matters... running this on a 64 bit Windows, the program is compiled for target x86 though.

edit: The reason I'm pretty sure the unmanaged methods are responsible is the way this Stack Trace of the AccessViolationException looks ("bei"="at"):

```
bei System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   bei McDonaldsVote.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\McDonaldsVote\McDonaldsVote\Program.cs:Zeile 22.
```

Comment: When you say "the complete system (OS) crashes," do you mean the system bluescreens?  It becomes unstable?  It restarts?  Some system process crashes and restarts (or doesn't restart)?

Comment: can you include your code on the timer part. i have encountered crashing problems
and most of it comes from a continues running timer function/method. some timer cause your program to continuously stores a data and dont disposed it. especially if your making a multi threaded timers..

Comment: Q: Have you tried running this program under the VS20xx debugger, and doesn't the debugger catch the exception (without crashing your system)?  Q: When you got bluescreens, did you get any dump files? Have you examined them with WinDbg?  Q: Exactly a) which Windows version?  b) which VS20xx version?  c) Which .Net version are you targetting?

Comment: I was either asleep or not at home when it happened, so I can't personally tell what happens exactly. Only thing I see is that the computer is turned off, and on reboot it gives me the "special" windows start options that appear when you hard-reboot. A friend of mine had my program running too, and he got a bluescreen.

Comment: paulsm4: The debugger (in my Visual Studio 2008 Professional) catches the AccessViolationException at "Application.Run(new Form1());" (which is hardly of any use), but that only happens if the system does NOT crash.
don't have any dump files, don't really know what you mean by that. I'm running Windows 7 Professional

Comment: The timer code is kind of messed up, it would take some time to organize it properly to show here. I really doubt though that this is the reason, a complete OS crash should not happen from integrated timers, would be the first time I hear about that. Also, I included above the StackTrace that makes me think that the unmanaged methods are wrong.

Comment: Hi again, i check those .dll files that you use in your program, and gdi32.dll caught my attention. i got this scenarios that when i use a new .dll in a program i did encounter a sudden BSOD. here's what i found out about gdi32.dll http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/558279-blue-screen-stop-error-please.html they have problems using gdi32.dll and it causes them to have BSOD too, i dont know if this will help you, but this is what im thinking right now.

Comment: Katherina: thanks for that. Possibly that one is the reason, still, they didn't seem to have figured out what's wrong there. My intuition is telling me this is somewhat of an 32/64 bit problem. I'm going to sleep now and leave the program running on my 32 bit Windows 7 Laptop, see if it crashes there too.
@paulsm4: forgot your last point: I'm targetting 3.5

Comment: @Chris - Is this something that could better be accomplished with [Test Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163288.aspx) or [similar](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=.net%20ui%20automation%20framework&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=f1e01be211cb938c&biw=1366&bih=634&pf=p&pdl=500) managed UI framework? Even using the COM version of AutoIT would be better than manually invoking the API calls.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but are you sure that this automatic logging off behavior is related to your program?  If you are not running the program and you leave the machine alone for a few hours, what happens?  The reason that I ask is that what you are describing sounds much more like failing hardware or maybe power outages than anything caused by software.

Comment: @M.Babcock - This is not a test program. More like a click bot. The clicks are performed on a flash object within a webcontrol. Don't know about a way to automate without doing it ugly like this.

Comment: @ChrisShain - No such thing as a stupid question ;) But I'm fairly sure it was the program. My PC loves me, and it usually doesn't do that to me - and it often runs for long periods. And this has happened two nights in a row, which excludes power outages in my opinion, they're not so frequent here. Also, as I said, a friend was able to catch a blue screen. I have to say, though, that bluescreen was before i fixed the mouse_event definition - I had longs instead of uint parameters in there, [this site](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/321029-how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-in-c/) showed it wrong.

Comment: Had my notebook running through the night now without a problem. Maybe it really WAS just a power outage last night, and I already fixed the problem yesterday.. or it's a 32/64 bit problem, as I suspected... it's frustrating that this needs at least 6 hours of constant running to be more or less sure.